# form data disappear whenever page reloaded (react)

Tags: forms, validation, shadcnui

i fetch date from an api and im useing shadcn library for the form, the issue im facing is that the default value for the inputs are working just fine whenever i navigate to the page the problem is when i reload the page the data disappear.
what i want is the default data to appear at all time and to be changeable, because it seems like the form defaultValues are not getting updated whenever the data get fetched
any feedback will be appreciated.
thank you!

this is some of the code i uses

this is the form validation

```
const formSchema = z.object({
  first_name: z.string().min(1, 'Fistname is required'),
  second_name: z.string().min(1, 'Secondname is required'),
  last_name: z.string().min(1, 'Lastname is required'),
  email: z.string().email('Invalid Email'),
  phone: z.any(),
  
  birth_country: z.number().min(1, { message: "pirth day is required."}),
  birth_city: z.number().min(1, { message: "pirth city is required."}),
  birth_date: z.any({required_error: "A date of birth is required."}),
  residence_country: z.number().min(1, { message: "residence country is required"}),
  residence_city: z.number().min(1, { message: "residence city is required"}),
  gender: z.number({required_error: "Please select a gender."}),
  
  education_institute: z.number({required_error: "Please select education institution."}),
  nationality: z.number({required_error: "Please select a nationality."}),
  education_level: z.number({required_error: "Please select education level."}),
  occupation: z.number({required_error: "Please select an occupation."}),
  experience_years: z.number({required_error: "Please select years of experience."}),
  major: z.number().min(1, { message: "please select major"}),
  skills: z.array(z.number()).min(1, 'Skills is required'),
  // skills: z.number().min(1, 'Skills is required'),

})
```

data fetching

```
 const { data: userData } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['userData'],
    queryFn: async () => 
    await api().get(`/individual/user_data`).then((res) => {
      return res.data as FormDataProps;
    })
  })
```

zodResolver for the defualt values

```
   const form = useForm<z.infer<typeof formSchema>>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      first_name: userData && userData?.first_name || undefined,
      second_name: userData && userData?.second_name || undefined,
      last_name: userData && userData?.last_name || undefined,
      email: userData && userData?.email || undefined,
      phone: userData && userData?.phone,
      
      birth_country: userData && userData.birth_country.id || undefined,
      birth_city: userData && userData?.birth_city.id || undefined,
      // birth_date: userData && userData?.birth_date || undefined,
      residence_country: userData && userData?.residence_country.id || undefined,
      residence_city: userData && userData?.residence_city.id || undefined,
      gender: userData && userData?.gender.id || undefined,
      
      nationality: userData && userData?.nationality.id || undefined,
      education_institute: userData && userData?.education_institute.id || undefined,
      education_level: userData && userData?.education_level.id || undefined,
      major: userData && userData?.major.id || undefined,
      experience_years: userData && userData?.experience_years.id || undefined,
      occupation: userData && userData?.occupation.id || undefined,
      skills: currenUserSkills || undefined,
  
    },
  })
```

this is some of the form

```
                  <form
                    onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(submitForm)}
                    className="space-y-2 mt-5"
                  >

                    <div className='flex flex-col md:flex-row flex-wrap gap-5 w-full'>
                      <div className='w-full flex-1'>
                        <FormField
                          control={form.control}
                          name="first_name"
                          render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormItem>
                              <FormLabel>
                                  <Translatable>
                                    Firstname
                                  </Translatable>
                                </FormLabel>
                              <FormControl>
                                <Input
                                  // disabled={isSubmitting}
                                  placeholder="firstname"
                                  {...field}
                                />
                              </FormControl>
                              <FormMessage/> 
                            </FormItem>
                          )}
                        />
                      </div>

                      <div className='w-full flex-1'>
                        <FormField
                          control={form.control}
                          name="second_name"
                          render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormItem>
                              <FormLabel>
                                  <Translatable>
                                    Middlename
                                  </Translatable>
                                </FormLabel>
                              <FormControl>
                                <Input
                                  // disabled={isSubmitting}
                                  placeholder="second name'"
                                  {...field}
                                />
                              </FormControl>
                              <FormMessage/> 
                            </FormItem>
                          )}
                        />
                      </div>

                      <div className='w-full flex-1'>
                        <FormField
                          control={form.control}
                          name="last_name"
                          render={({ field }) => (
                            <FormItem>
                              <FormLabel>
                                  <Translatable>
                                    Lastname
                                  </Translatable>
                                </FormLabel>
                              <FormControl>
                                <Input
                                  // disabled={isSubmitting}
                                  placeholder="lastname'"
                                  {...field}
                                />
                              </FormControl>
                              <FormMessage/> 
                            </FormItem>
                          )}
                        />
                      </div>

                    </div>
</form>
                </Form>
```